# How to point to jdni.properties file to set properties in Java

Tags: java, properties, jndi

I can use System.getProperties() method to set properties in Java.

```
System.getProperties().put("java.naming.factory.initial",
 "fr.dyade.aaa.jndi2.client.NamingContextFactory"); 
System.getProperties().put("java.naming.factory.host", "localhost");
System.getProperties().put("java.naming.factory.port", "16400");
```

How can I get the same effect by reading the properties stored in a file?

When I have a jdni.properties with the following content:

```
java.naming.factory.initial  fr.dyade.aaa.jndi2.client.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.host localhost
java.naming.factory.port 16400
```

How can I teach Java to read them as properties?
I use eclipse for development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jdni.properties should be in the class path.
In eclipse, I had to use `Advanced` tab in Run Configuration/CLASSPATH to add the directory to be included as class path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a ready feature - Properties.load(InputStream inStream)

Comment: This has zero effect on JNDI.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in the root directory of one of your JAR files, or in WEB-INF/classes in a WAR file.

Comment: Where I said. I don't see what Eclipse has to do with it.